# Gnome built-in night light won't work after update

Tags: nvidia, gnome, xorg, 17.10

I recently updated from 17.04 to 17.10 cause EOL of the former. I decided to switch from redshift to the inbuilt night light which is not affecting at all my color temperature. I cannot even see my display in the color section in settings.
I'm on an asus ux430uq i915 drivers (nvidia disabled by prime) on Ubuntu 17.10 on Xorg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem came after the NoMachine installation. 
(Note that if you don't have NoMachine installed, the problem may be caused by other factors)

Deleting the file `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device.policy` and reinstalling the `colord` package, solved the issue (after a reboot).

[Source](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=228663)

The problem was still there after upgrading to 18.04. The solution  is the same.